# Console.log not outputting json

Tags: javascript, json, global-variables, console.log

```js
var _json = [{"codigo": "1", "nome": "Robert Santos", "turma": "EM2A"}, {"codigo": "2", "nome": "Eduardo Alves Silveira", "turma": "EM3A"}, {"codigo": "3", "nome": "Amara Gouveia", "turma": "EMT2B"}, {"codigo": "4", "nome": "Tainá Belchior da Silva", "turma": "EF5B"}];

function console() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(_json, null, 4));
}

console();
```

Hi, i'm using this code, but when I try execute `console()`, i'm getting this error: `TypeError: console.log is not a function`

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Rename your function ``console`` to something else. It will work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting `TypeError: console.log is not a function` because you're overwriting the `console` object in the global scope with your own function called `console` which doesn't have a `log` function. You can solve this issue by renaming your function to something else, snippet example:

```js
var _json = [{"codigo": "1","nome": "Robert Santos","turma": "EM2A"}, 
{"codigo": "2","nome": "Eduardo Alves Silveira","turma": "EM3A"},{"codigo": 
"3","nome": "Amara Gouveia","turma": "EMT2B"},{"codigo": "4","nome": "Tainá Belchior da Silva","turma": "EF5B"}];

function log() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(_json, null, 4));
}

log();
```

Answer (score 1):

The global `window` object already has a function named `console`, which you are trying to override with your own `console` function.  Just rename your `console` function to something else.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot name your function `console`**

**Reason** - `Console` is an existing object in JavaScript that provides access to the browser's debugging console. Read [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) to know more about it

**Corrected Code**

```js
var _json = [{"codigo": "1","nome": "Robert Santos","turma": "EM2A"}, 
{"codigo": "2","nome": "Eduardo Alves Silveira","turma": "EM3A"},{"codigo": 
"3","nome": "Amara Gouveia","turma": "EMT2B"},{"codigo": "4","nome": "Tainá Belchior da Silva","turma": "EF5B"}];

function logger() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(_json, null, 4));
}

logger();
```